# Cloudrail - Twitter API - GetIdentifier fails

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, cloudrail

I'm using cloudrail-node-js v.2.17.3.
I want to simply get an unique Identifier for Twitter Authentication.

However, this always returns an error :

```
{ [Error: The URL the RedirectReceiver returns does not contain all necessary keys in the query, it's missing at least oauth_token,oauth_verifier]
  message: 'The URL the RedirectReceiver returns does not contain all necessary keys in the query, it\'s missing at least oauth_token,oauth_verifier' }
```

Here is my code :

```
const cloudrail = require('cloudrail-si');

cloudrail.Settings.setKey(cloudrailKey);
let Service = new cloudrail.services.Twitter(cloudrail.RedirectReceivers.getLocalAuthenticator(3000), twitterKey, twitterSecret, `http://localhost:3000`, "state");

Service.getIdentifier(function (err, id) {
    console.log(err, id);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly happens when you call the getIdentifier method? Does the website where you have to sign in show?

Comment: @Dr.GIT Yes, the Twitter pop-up appears well, asking for permissions.